# Own project via composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I've got some libraries loaded through composer, and I'm wondering if it's possible to add my own library in the /vendor map, and then to have the composer autoloader load it? The structure would be something like /vendor/mylibrary/ and then a namespace mylibrary.

Would this be possible? Also would it be possible to add a different map to the composer autoloader? Like for example /app/src/ and then to have it load all the classes in that folder? Or do I have to make my own loader for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading the [composer documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading):

> You can even add your own code to the autoloader by adding an autoload field to composer.json.
>
> ```
> {
>     "autoload": {
>         "psr-0": {"Acme": "src/"}
>     }
> ```
>
> }
>
> Composer will register a PSR-0 autoloader for the Acme namespace.
>   You define a mapping from namespaces to directories. The src directory would be in your project root, on the same level as vendor directory is. An example filename would be src/Acme/Foo.php containing an Acme\Foo class.
>
> After adding the autoload field, you have to re-run install to
>   re-generate the vendor/autoload.php file.

So basically, you just need to [follow PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md), and tell composer where to find your library, by adding that line to your composer.json

Comment: Note that PSR-0 is not required, just recommended. In my case I want to put all the libraries specific to my app in a "lib" folder, but since they all belong to my app it seemed redundant to have a subfolder for the namespace (e.g. `MyApp`). I thought of using `"autoload": {"classmap": ["lib"]}`, but that seems to break down for sub-components, e.g. a `lib/foo` directory containing classes with the namespace `MyApp\Foo`. So now I'm wondering if I should just stick with putting my app-specific libraries in `vendor`, which I'm guessing is the intended usage.

Comment: @MattBrowne Hopefully you didn't put them into `vendor/` since that is composer's space rather than your application's, but did you ever find a solution to that? I would prefer to avoid redundant psr-0 directories under `src/` and allow the application's core directories to live there without duplicating the whole namespace (which has `VendorName\ProjectName` above the core files to autoload). As far as any docs or examples I have found, Composer can't do that.

Comment: No, I realized they shouldn't go in vendor. Unfortunately the only way to avoid the redundant folder structure for now is to write your own autoloader (to be used in addition to composer's autoloader). See my rejected pull request: https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/1985

Comment: Update: Composer now supports the new PSR-4 standard, which will allow you to do what I described above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.You can achieve it. Configure your composer.json file as following:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [ "classes" ]
}
```

Here classes is the name of the directory  where you have all your application related classes.Vendor related class should be auto detected as well. Just add the following line to achieve both at the same time:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

And you can use the namesapce to reference your class like the following:

```
use classes\Model\Article;
```

Comment: `use classes\Model\Article; ` that's what is was looking for, exactly how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it is possible to add own libraries and you should feel highly encouraged to do so. If your library is available publicly, you can simply register it at packagist.org. If not, it's a bit more complicated, but not impossible.

If your project does not follow the PSR-0 standard, composer will create a classmap for you. A custom autoloader is not supported.

I'd recommend you to read the (really excellent) documentation about all this and come back, if you're running into problems.

http://getcomposer.org/doc/